# Firebase: Switch current database [iOS and Android]

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have chat application based on soket.io with more than 5k users online right now and lots of problems with connection stability, load balancing and so on. We have no experienced backend engineer, so we looking on to the Firebase.

My questions are:

- Is there are way to determine max allowed connections error type
- Is there are legal way to change client to another backend when more
  than 10k connections already established to the current DB?
- Is there
  are better way to workaround 10k connections limit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebase projects on a paid plan, there is (according to the [Firebase Pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)):

> There is an initial limit of 10,000 simultaneous database connections. See FAQ section for more information

From that [FAQ section on this initial limit](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#faq-simultaneous):

> The Flame and Blaze Plans have an initial limit of 10,000 simultaneous database connections. This is to prevent abuse and can be raised by [contacting Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) with 24 hours notice.

So: once you have decent usage and want the limit raised, reach out to Firebase Support to have it raised.